# In Cordova Ionic Background process is not working when i remove app from stack

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ibeacon, ngcordova

I build a app using i-beacon plugin. My project is running fine in most of cases. But in one case its create problem.

When application is running in background, foreground and if app in not running my application find i-beacons correctly and working fine.

But when i send application in background and remove from stack then whole process is also stop and application not find beacons. but in this case background process is still running. but not find beacons.

Help if you know more about this..

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem, ...

here is the problem occurs due to cordova whitelist plugin..

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"/>
```

just add this line on your header

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"/>

</head>
```

It solve my problem.